# VB.NET How to get saved image location?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I'm browsing photos(lets say from C:/pictures/) from a form and saving it to another folder(D:/savedimages/). How can I get the imagelocation in the savedimages folder? I need to save the path in my SQL.

This is the code I'm using in getting and saving img:

```
Dim filename As String
Dim getlocation As String
Sub saveimg()
    'Get next studid
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM student", conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        filename = (reader.GetInt32(0))
    End While
    reader.Close()

    'Save image
    Dim path As String = ".\Photos\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) And PictureBox1.ImageLocation <> Nothing Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(".\Photos\" & filename & ".png")
    ElseIf PictureBox1.ImageLocation <> Nothing Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(".\Photos\" & filename & ".png")
    End If
    getlocation = ".\Photos\" & filename & ".png"
End Sub
```

Code when I'm saving the path into database, unfortunately it doesn't save any data.

```
Dim list As ListViewItem
Sub addstud()
    Dim strings As String = "INSERT INTO student (img) VALUES ('" & getlocation & "')"
    Dim sqlcommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim Table As New DataTable
    With sqlcommand
        .CommandText = strings
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    With sqladapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlcommand
        .Fill(Table)
    End With
    Main.lvStudent.Items.Clear()
    For x As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
        list = Main.lvStudent.Items.Add(Table(x)("id").ToString.PadLeft(4, "0"))
        With list
            .SubItems.Add(Table(x)("lname").ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Table(x)("fname").ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Table(x)("mname").ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Table(x)("yearlevel").ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Table(x)("section").ToString)
        End With
        With Main.lvStudent
            .Items(x).Font = New Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
        End With
    Next
    saveimg()
    MessageBox.Show("Student successfully added!")
End Sub
```

Example of what i want to happen:
I browsed image1.jpg from C:/pictures/ and I'm going to save it in D:/savedimages/, now I want to save the path in sql = D:/savedimages/image1.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific error ?

Comment: it doesnt save the path in sql

Comment: So everything runs smooth but path not saved in db ? Have you checked the vales you are inserting using **Breakpoint** ?

Comment: check the value of `getlocation` by putting breakpoint.it should be null.

Comment: It saves the path now when I put the saveimg() in top inside the addstud().. but it only saves ./Photos/image1.png . What I want is the whole path like D:/blablabla/Photos/image1.png.

Comment: but for saving to path `D:/blablabla/Photos/image1.png` you have given `Dim path As String = ".\Photos\"`. if u want to save it that specific path give the correct path as `Dim path As String = "D:/Photos/"`

Comment: bye the way does your image gets saved using this code?

Comment: if I change the path in that way, I think It will throw an error if I use this in another computer which doesn't have that location. and nope, i dont save image in sql, only imagepath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.IO.DirectoryInfo like the following

```
Dim path As String = ".\Photos\"
Dim dir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo 'for saving folder name
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) And PictureBox1.ImageLocation <> Nothing Then
    dir = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    getlocation = dir.FullName & filename & ".png"
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(getlocation)
ElseIf PictureBox1.ImageLocation <> Nothing Then
    getlocation = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).FullName & filename & ".png"
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(getlocation)
End If
```

Comment: Almost! :D But it doesn't show backslash "\" in the path. it shows like this D:ImagesPhotosFilename.png

Comment: Really? it does on mine though. Try using breakpoints.

Or you mean the value inserted in the table does not have "\"? You should escape backslashes. :)

Comment: check the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261220/escape-a-string-add-slashes-in-vb-net